# Chrome extension popup flickering issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use a popup for my chrome extension, and I add items to the popup's DOM via jquery. When I add items, it keeps flickering infinitely.

There seems to be a related discussion in [chromium bugs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31970), but setting the width doesn't help too.

Is there any work around?

PS:My entire code is available in [github](https://github.com/alagu/PNR-Chrome-Extension).

Comment: Hi Alagu, were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey Sai, it isn't flickering now. I don't exactly remember what I did (this is 3 years back :-)

Answer (score 1):

(Unfortunately can't see the extension in action, because I don't have a PNR number :(, but I can see this with the Webpage Screenshot extension.)

As a workaround, does it help if you set the width of div.parent-wrap, rather than the body element?

Are you only getting this on Mac, as per the Chromium bug report?

Answer (score 1):

This is a super old question, but for whoever stumbling across this in the hope to find a solution. I had the exact same problem where the Popup window would flicker and start shaking left / right as soon as I opened it. This would happen only when I changed the width of one of the elements (slider) from 50% to anything above 50%.

```css
.container {
  min-width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide1">Slide 1 Content</div>
    <div class="slide2">Slide 2 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What fixed the issue for me was just to add a `max-width` attribute to my container. This stopped the flickering/shaking of the pop-up window.

```css
.container {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Looks like a Chrome bug.